# Clone a vuejs component, retaining the props and other characteristics of the original component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component like this

```
<jesus>
    <bread flavour="fishes"></bread>
</jesus>
```

I want to take the bread before compilation, multiply it, and put it back.

This is what I have done for the moment:

```
beforeCompile () {
  // take it away because I don't want it to be compiled yet
  this.breadEl = this.$options._content.querySelector('bread')
  this.$options._content.removeChild(this.breadEl)
},
compiled () {
  var jesusEl = this.$el
  var breadStampEl = this.breadEl.outerHTML
  // this will return the options for a prototype component
  // the el will duplicate the HTML every time (maybe cache it?)
  var breadStampOptions = Object.assign({}, {el () {
    let el = document.createElement('div')
    jesusEl.appendChild(el)
    el.outerHTML = breadStampEl
    el = jesusEl.querySelector('bread')
    return el
  }})
  var bread1 = new this.$options.components.bread(breadStampOptions)
  var bread2 = new this.$options.components.child(breadStampOptions)
  jesusEl.querySelector('#bread1').appendChild(bread1.$el)
  jesusEl.querySelector('#bread2').appendChild(bread2.$el)
}
```

With the jesus template having the `<div id="bread1">` `<div id="bread2">` inside it.

Is there a better/native way to clone a component, **including the props**?

Attached a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mobbtqdv/10/

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not entierly sure what you're trying to do… why do you need to clone the components? What is the actual idea behind all of your efforts?

Comment: I want the user to enter his components, I will manipulate them and fill a table. But I want to bring with me the props the user entered and all the other things, like content distribution.

Comment: I'm still really lost... what does *I want the user to enter his components* mean? How does the user enter components? And where is the table you mention? Also, what do you mean with content distribution?

Comment: I mean as an API to another component. Content distribution https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Comment: Also not sure what you are trying to do. You don't need to clone components. They themselves are reusable. If you want to share the data between components you need to define a data object and bind it to each component

Comment: You are right but they are not my components, they are the urser's I cannot control them, but I have to be sure they behave as expected by the user. If the user enters a prop he expects it to be on each clone

Comment: *You don't need to clone components*. Exactly. Did I understand you correctly in that the user passes in only one component, and you will clone it?

Comment: In general no, but for the sake of this question, yes. Let's say the user passes one component. With a prop. I want that prop to be replicated in cloned components. Also I updated my fiddle, now it doesn't work anymore. In particular, you can see that when the data changes in the parent, it doesn't trigger a redraw of the children.